# Trying to display bars on a map with D3, getting Error: <rect> attribute height: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected length, ""

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and web development in general. I copied parts of this code from Elijah Meeks: http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/4531633 where he was successfully able to display bars representing data, on a map, as if putting a scattered bar graph on a map.

I am loading the JSON from outside, created a variable in the JSON called drugDeaths and renamed the JSON file as .js. The data is huge, it represents drug-induced deaths from each county in the US, obtained from the CDC. I'm trying to display the drug-induced deaths per county and associate this number with the height of bars centered on the county's centroid on the map. So it's possible there are thousands bars to be visualized.

The format of the data appears like this (you can see it here https://github.com/allanrimban/allanrimban.github.io/tree/master/maps/drug_deaths_county):

```
 {
     "X": -113.758151046471,
     "Y": 35.7045834851058,
     "GEOID": 4015,
     "LONG": -113.7582,
     "LAT": 35.7046,
     "County": "Mohave County, AZ",
     "Deaths": 63,
     "Population": 205249,
     "Crude Rate": 30.7,
     "coordinates": "-113.7582,35.7046"
 },
 {
     "X": -90.4054985445433,
     "Y": 30.6267806285343,
     "GEOID": 22105,
     "LONG": -90.4055,
     "LAT": 30.6268,
     "County": "Tangipahoa Parish, LA",
     "Deaths": 38,
     "Population": 130710,
     "Crude Rate": 29.1,
     "coordinates": "-90.4055,30.6268"
 },
```

My code is below but it does nothing. Nothing appears on the page, just all white. What am I missing? Can D3 handle a file as big as the file in quetsion? 
I appreciate any feedback. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Drug_Deaths_County_Simple_JSON.js"></script>
</head>
<body>        
    <script>

        var width = 960, height = 960;
        scaleVal = 1000;            
        rotateVal = 30;

        var svg = d3.select('body')
                            .append('svg')
                            .attr('width', width)
                            .attr('height', height);
        projection = d3.geoAlbers()              
          .scale(scaleVal)
          .rotate([121.00, -35.50, 20])
          .center([-4, 5]);


        var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        bars = svg.selectAll("g")
          .data(drugDeaths)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "bars")
          .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates) + ")";});
        bars.append("rect")               
            .attr('height',  function(d) {return d.Deaths})
            .attr('width', 1)
            .attr('y', function(d) {return -(d.Deaths)})
            .attr("class", "bars")
            .style("fill", "green")
            .style("stroke", "white")
            .style("stroke-width", 2);

        bars.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 1)
        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");                            


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#_projection you see a string is not allowed. And the coords need to be longitude, latitude.

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection([d.LONG, d.LAT]) + ")";});
```

For some reason the rects give an error in `height`. Setting the `.bars` style solved it.

```
bars.append("rect")
    .attr('height', function(d) {return d.Deaths})
    .attr('width', 2)
    .attr('y', function(d) {return -(d.Deaths)})
    .attr("class", "bars");
```

CSS

```
.bars {
fill: green;
stroke: white;
stroke-width: 1;
}
```

Comment: That worked. I don't know how the example I copied from (Elijah Meeks) made it work. Could it be due to difference in versions of D3?

Comment: @AllanRimban: if you look at the example `"coordinates": [-122.682,45.52]`